# In DolphinDB, how do i Import data for special time types?

Tags: datetime, parsing, dolphindb, nanotime

I have data as follows:
Identifier, Domain, DateTime, GMT Offset, Type, Bid, Ask, ExchTime, BidYld, AskYld, Date
CN180210=,MarketPrice, 2019-01-01T00:07:30.456396320Z,0,Quote,103.124,103.732,,3.643,3.568,2019/1/2
...

How should I handle 2019-01-01T00:07:30.456396320Z?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DolphinDB function 'temporalParse':

```
t=table("2019-01-01T00:07:30.456396320Z" as x)
update t set z=temporalParse(x, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnnZ");
```